# Easiest way to validate a date/time field in an MS Access continuous form?

Tags: vba, validation, ms-access, continuous-forms

Basic access user here, I have a date/time field in a continuous form (subform, part of a main form) which users need to fill in, but I need it validated so that for every new record that date/time field's value is at least 10 minutes after the previous one. Is there an easy way to do it, preferably in the form using vba?

Comment: AfterUpdate event of control sets a global variable or an UNBOUND textbox or a TempVar. BeforeUpdate event of same control compares that saved value with current input. When you have code with specific issue, post question.

Comment: Thank you so much! Got it to work via an unbound textbox